# Cannot find how to run parse on my ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, parse-platform

I am new to parse! Web developer mostly work on PHP based projects.

I got new already running project on the parse server. It is hosted on the ubuntu server.

Project is already running. But, I don't know from where to start to understand flow of the project!

I am trying to find the dashboard/admin panel where I can find some APIs and check how to run/modify them.

I am trying:

```
http://ipaddress:1337/parse
and
http://domain:1337/parse
```

But, its giving me error:

```
{"error":"unauthorized"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You've gotten Parse Server hosted which just hosts the API. You'll need to host Parse-Dashboard as well if you want to view the dashboard/admin panel. Or you can just start digging into the PHP docs: http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your parse-dashboard-config.json file.

Your app detail is like below:

```
 "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
    "appId": "appId",
    "masterKey": "masterKey",
    "appName": "appname"
  }]
```

If ok then you have to try: http://yourserver:4040/apps

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 — Install Node.js and Development Tools
Begin by changing the current working path to your sudo user's home directory:

```
cd ~
```

NodeSource offers an Apt repository for Debian and Ubuntu Node.js packages. We'll use it to install Node.js. NodeSource offers an installation script for the the latest stable release (v5.5.0 at the time of this writing), which can be found in the installation instructions. Download the script with curl:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

You can review the contents of this script by opening it with nano, or your text editor of choice:

```
nano ./nodesource_setup.sh
```

Next, run nodesource_setup.sh. The -E option to sudo tells it to preserve the user's environment variables so that they can be accessed by the script:

```
sudo -E bash ./nodesource_setup.sh
```

Once the script has finished, NodeSource repositories should be available on the system. We can use apt-get to install the nodejs package. We'll also install the build-essential metapackage, which provides a range of development tools that may be useful later, and the Git version control system for retrieving projects from GitHub:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential git
```

Step 2 — Install an Example Parse Server App
Parse Server is designed to be used in conjunction with Express, a popular web application framework for Node.js which allows middleware components conforming to a defined API to be mounted on a given path. The parse-server-example repository contains a stubbed-out example implementation of this pattern.

Retrieve the repository with git:

```
git clone https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example.git
```

Enter the parse-server-example directory you just cloned:

```
cd ~/parse-server-example
```

Use npm to install dependencies, including parse-server, in the current directory:

```
npm install
```

npm will fetch all of the modules required by parse-server and store them in ~/parse-server-example/node_modules.

Use npm to start the service. This will run a command defined in the start property of package.json. In this case, it runs node index.js:

```
npm start
```

Output

> parse-server-example@1.0.0 start /home/sammy/parse-server-example
>   node index.js
>   parse-server-example running on port 1337.

You can terminate the running application at any time by pressing Ctrl-C.

step 4

to install parse dashboard

```
npm install -g parse-dashboard
```

then you can access it through

```
http://yourserver:1337/dashboard
```

Comment: The setup for parse is already running on my server. I just need to find if it has dashboard or not. I also need to check if I can get which APIs have been added and what is the logic behind that.

Comment: I have tired with default URLs that could be possible to get the dashboard URLs as per described in my question. I hope it will help you to get my question and what I need to know.

Comment: You should install the dashboard like in step 4 in my answer